# Compile OpenCV with Cuda fails

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, cuda, cmake

I'm trying to build opencv with gpu functionality. So I need to compile opencv with cuda.
I've downloaded opencv, also I installed cuda with http://wiki.accelereyes.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_CUDA_Under_Ubuntu_10.04 tutorial on my ubuntu.

When I try to `cmake -D WITH_CUDA=ON` on the output it says

> Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version ".", but required is at
>   least "4.0" (found /usr/local/cuda)

this problem is driving me crazy! I can't get it working! I'm sure that all environment variables and path are correct for cuda.

Any solutions you might think of?

Answer (score 3):

I made this tutorial myself (well I actually gathered it). I tried it on ubuntu 11.10 and I think its a good start for beginners like me. Hope it's of some use.

1-CUDA does not work with gcc 4.5 or higher so if your gcc version is higher you should install gcc 4.4:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc-4.4 g++-4.4
```

2-Now download and install the appropriate CUDA driver:

```
$ sudo apt-get install \
nvidia-current \
nvidia-current-dev \
nvidia-current-updates \
nvidia-current-updates-dev
```

3-Download CUDA toolkit and SDK from nvidia website (http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
Notice that some versions of CUDA drivers only work with specific versions of toolkit (for example (driver 280.13 works with toolkit 4.0 or lower). So further on if you encountered an error message indicating that CUDA driver and runtime do not match you should go back and install a lower version of toolkit. Don’t worry during the reinstallation process it will remove the previous one even if it is a higher version.
You can check the CUDA driver version by:

```
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

You can check toolkit version by:

```
nvcc –version
```

4-Copy and install the two .run files you just downloaded:
    $ Chmod +x (name of the file)
    $ ./(name of the file)

5-To compile SDK examples you also need this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev libxi-dev
```

And create these linkes

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libXmu.so.6 /usr/lib/libXmu.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

6-Add CUDA to your path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

7-Now add library paths:

```
cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia_settings.conf  \
/usr/lib/nvidia-setting  \
/usr/local/cuda/lib64 \
/usr/local/cuda/lib

sudo ldconfig
```

8-Now go to the NVIDIA_GPU_COMPUTING_SDK_... folder and open the file C/common/common.mk with a text editor like vim and change these lines:

```
LINKFLAGS  +=
```

To
    LINKFLAGS  += -L/usr/lib/nvidia-current

And
    NVCCFLAGS  :=
To
    NVCCFLAGS  :=  -ccbin  /usr/bin/gcc-4.4

9-Finally you should compile and run an example to confirm that the installation is complete. Again go to NVIDIA_GPU_COMPUTING_SDK  folder and run make:

```
sudo make
```

To run the examples go to NVIDIA_GPU_COMPUTING_SDK/C/bin/linux/release
And run an example by:
    ./(name of one of the files in the folder)

10-Later when you want to write your own CUDA program you should edit one of the examples in the NVIDIA_GPU_COMPUTING_SDK folder and compile it like you just did for the examples.

Here are some websites you can refer to:

[Source1](http://www.dickscheid.net/2011/10/19-cuda-ubuntu-1110/)
[Source2](http://blog.ryant.org/2011/12/installing-cuda-toolkit-on-ubuntu-1110.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check the CUDA_ARCH_BIN value. It should be 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.0 or something like this.

And also check the CUDA_ARCH_PTX and make sure it is correct and suits your architecture. Theoretically, it may be null, buh who knows?